# Apache redirect with RewriteCond not working

Tags: apache, redirect, mod-rewrite

I am looking a way to rewrite the below url:

`faleconosco.aeiou.com.br/Email.do?tela=2&auth=N&skin=Sac`

to

`10.13.2.1:9080`

I already tried several differents ways: All not worked

Any help will be glad

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} =contact/Email\.do?tela=2&auth=N&skin=Sac [NC]
RewriteRule http://10.13.2.1:9080 [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} =faleconosco.aeiou.com.br/contact/Email.do?tela=2&auth=N&skin=Sac
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ 10.13.2.1:9080/$1 [R=301]


RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} (a-z).aeiou.com.br/contact/Email.do?tela=2&auth=N&skin=Sac
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ 10.13.2.1:9080/$1 [R=301]
```

Any assistance will be glad

Comment: All your attempts are for a path that starts with `/contact/`, but that isn't in the URL you said you are trying to match ...?

Comment: And the host name is only `faleconosco.aeiou.com.br` of course, and not what you are trying to check for in attempt 2 & 3.

Comment: `%{REQUEST_URI}` contains `/Email.do`, `%{HTTP_HOST}` - `faleconosco.aeiou.com.br`, `%{QUERY_STRING}` - `tela=2&auth=N&skin=Sac`. An `http://` domain prefix is a must.